# Elixir Struct definition

Tags: elixir

Structs are extensions built on top of maps. However, I was expecting the struct definition to be like,

```
defmodule User do
  defstruct %{name: "John", age: 27}
end
```

However, I was surprised find that the fields need to be defined as Keyword Lists.

```
defmodule User do
  defstruct [name: "John", age: 27]
end
```

I find this odd, is there a reason for this notation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it allows you to use 2 different notations:

```
defstruct [:name, :age]
```

if there is no default value or:

```
defstruct [name: "John", age: 27]
```

if there are default values. You can even mix these two:

```
defstruct [:name, age: 27]
```

Additional if you use keyword list you can omit `[]` which is sometimes handy.

Comment: I see, so it looks like it is purely for syntactic sugar. I also just found out that you can do this when declaring maps: ` %{name: "John", name: "Jose", age: 27}`